# Printing all sets in list python

Tags: python, list

```
fob=open('c:/Users/username/Desktop/CE151 Python/ass2/grid.txt','r')
text_file = open("grid.txt","r")
for item in fob:
    tuple(item.split(';')[0:])
print(item[0:])
```

I have loaded a text file and I am trying put each line into a list.When I can for the first line it prints only 1 line. Even when i call for all lines it still outputs 1 line. How do I print a line i request for.

grid.txt contains:

```
paghzkctudptjdphsztprhttl
sbsnakjwqbouftmgnjqbtlinu
tsewohvobdsduqjiffkyylodo
oukwwefroyamapmlrrpvdolop
cqkfxtlksjvtmtrsbycmqrrri
kfervlqidqaxaoanfqjlmcpjh
yoyywrbpfcjlfbcbbcoecspwl
twbxetyuyufvvmauawjmbwlqh
txokdexmdbtgvhpsvsqtmljdx
dcatenrehteoxqdgeueljtrrn
jarteqvtxejfsqddkbuhcysfq
hpdrowssapxtrxhpdxcdhicon
```

Comment: Since your text file contains no semicolons, what possible reason do you have for trying to split on them? Also -- what is the point of `text_file`? You seem to be trying to open the same file twice and assigning it to different variables.

Comment: You never assign the result of `tuple(item.split(';')[0:])` to a variable (or append it to a list. It just "disappears", and only the last `item` is left once you exit the loop.

Comment: The `for` loop doesn't seem to do anything.  You are making a tuple and immediately throwing it away.  Perhaps you want the `print` statement in the `for` loop?

Comment: `[0:]` is basically the whole list...

Comment: Add a variables `mylist = []` *before* the loop, then inside the loop, use `mylist.append(tuple(item.split(';')[0:]))` instead, and you should have what you want.

Comment: Except perhaps for the `tuple` part (which has nothing to do with `list`s or `set`s, as mentioned in the question; except for the splitting on `;`, see first comment; and except for `[0:]`, which includes all items and can be left off (see 4th comment). You may want to clarify your *actual* goal, because you'll have other problems after you solved this one.

Comment: fob=open('c:/Users/username/Desktop/CE151 Python/ass2/grid.txt','r')
mylist = []
for item in fob:
    mylist.append(item.split(';')[0:])
    print(item[1])
I have made changes but it only prints the first column. I am trying to print in rows. any help

Comment: Please update your original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fob=open('c:/Users/username/Desktop/CE151 Python/ass2/grid.txt','r')
text_file = open("grid.txt","r")
listy=[]
for elem in text_file.read().split('\n'):
   listy.append(elem)
text_file.close()
```

You could try this. The lines are stored in the list `listy`.